# How Print in normal order and then reverse it?

Tags: java

I have to enter a length of an array , how to  print the numbers in normal order and then reverse it!

**Example:**

Enter the length  of  the array:  3
  Enter int 1:  *56*
  Enter int 2:  *10*
  Enter int 3:  *20*
normal 
56
10
20
reverse
20
10
56

```
import java.util.Scanner;


 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   int ArrayL;    

   // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter the length of the   array: ");
    ArrayLh= keyboard.nextInt();

     // Create an array 
    double[] array = new double[ArrayL];

       for (int index = 0; index < ArrayL; index++)
   {
     System.out.print("Enter Int" +
                     (index + 1) + ": ");
     array[index] = keyboard.nextDouble();
   }    
  }
 }
```

Comment: We're waiting for the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for(int i=0; i<ArrayLength;i++){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
   }

for(int i=ArrayLength-1; i>=0; i--){
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much .. but it still going vertically !!

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do it like this:

```
    List<Double> list1 = Arrays.stream(arrays).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(list1);
    List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>(list1);
    Collections.reverse(list2);
    System.out.println(list2);
```

If you need to join elements with space then use this:

```
    String forwardText = list1.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(forwardText);
    String backwardText = list2.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(backwardText);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Printing Normal Order:**

`Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);`

**Printing Reverse order:**

```
Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new))
                .descendingIterator().forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```